# Can I apply lambda function to df column over specific rows?

Tags: python, function, lambda

New to python, so bear with me!

I have a function that applies random values to different columns in my df (depending on the column name; each column has specific random value range). For one specific function, I want to apply it to just half of my column. I attempted working with just my even rows to deal with this, but it seems it's not working. When I print out the first few rows, I can tell the column did not update. Would appreciate any help!

Here's what I've attempted:

```
    for col in df.columns:
        if 'shirt' in col:
            df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: np.random.randint(0,5))
        elif 'pants' in col:
            df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: np.random.randint(0,10))
        elif 'sweater' in col:
            df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: np.random.randint(0,50) if df.index.all() % 2 == 0 else np.NaN)
        else:
            pass
```

(had to add `.all()` bc I got a `Value Error: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous` error.)

Using the index to apply it to half of my dataframe is what I can think of, but this wouldn't work if I wanted to apply that lambda function to just 60% or 80% of my column and leave the rest as nulls.

This is what I get as a result of the code above:

```
    shirt_count  pant_count  sweater_count  
0            14            3            5 
1            18            3            7 
2             1            3            5 
3             7            1            9 
4             2            3            2
```

Would love any help as I've been staring at my screen for hours!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply separate functions to the even and odd rows of the 'sweater' column:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'shirt': [0,0,0,0,0], 'pants': [0,0,0,0,0], 'sweater': [0,0,0,0,0]})

for col in df.columns:
    if 'shirt' in col:
        df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: np.random.randint(0,5))
    elif 'pants' in col:
        df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: np.random.randint(0,10))
    elif 'sweater' in col:
        # random integers for even rows
        df[col][::2] = df[col][::2].apply(lambda x: np.random.randint(0,50))

        # na.NaN for odd rows
        df[col][1::2] = df[col][1::2].apply(lambda x: np.NaN)
    else:
        pass
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   shirt  pants  sweater
0      4      9      0.0
1      0      1      NaN
2      2      7     28.0
3      2      7      NaN
4      0      8     30.0
```